# .htaccess redirect to https is not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I am scratching my head from hours and tried many solutions but still I am unable to redirect my website to *https*.

Below is my **.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Another **.htaccess** I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Both are not working & I also tried many other solutions on stackoverflow. But none is working.
As a reference, Here is [https Link of my website.](https://seotoolzz.com)

Comment: Note: My hosting is from Godaddy.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem a year ago. Try to add **web.config** file on root directory where you placed your **.htaccess** file.

Copy & paste below code in **web.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```